# Azure Timer Functions: Locally setting “RunOnStartup to true” does not work as expected

Tags: azure-functions

Here is my function:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace ExpDataIngestionBot.AzureFunctions
{
    public static class RecurringFetch
    {
        [FunctionName("RecurringFetch")]
        public static void Run(
            [TimerTrigger("%TriggerIntervalInCRON%", RunOnStartup = true)]
            TimerInfo myTimer, 
            ILogger log, 
            ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

It does not execute at startup when ran locally from the Visual Studio instance.

Comment: Can you show your cron?

Comment: RunOnStartup = true work fine on my side.

Comment: I see it running now, I am not sure why it did not work earlier.

Comment: Is there way to specify its value as true locally and false for the app service instance.

Comment: Do you mean change to false in production?

Comment: RunOnStartup = true is only used for local debug. You don't need to set in other situations, the default value is false. On normal, the timetrigger attribute is like this: [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I do not have to modify code each time I have to run it locally.

Comment: I tried something like `[TimerTrigger("%TriggerIntervalInCRON%", RunOnStartup = "%RunOnStartup%" == "true")]` and setting `"RunOnStartup" = "true"` in my local.settings.json file, but it did not trigger the function locally on startup.

Comment: please dont do that, RunOnStartup only accept bool value(true and false). %% can not be accepted.

Comment: Any other ideas on how to set the value of RunOnStartup through a configuration value, so that I can set that configuration to true locally and false in app service?

Worst case, I may have to follow the second voted solution on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556621/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-run-a-timer-triggered-azure-function-locally-once

Comment: Yes, you can. Although it looks not good but it work. Please forget about Parametrize of RunOnStartUp, it is not possible.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can mention this as a feature request?

Comment: Hi, this is the link: [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback)