# Debug Azure Function locally with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I want to run a task every day at 5 am to write some data to the database to create some reports. For that I thought I could use **Azure Functions (Timer trigger)**. My goal is to first debug the function locally (using a local database) before publishing it to Azure. For this I have created a new Azure Functions project in **Visual Studio 2019** with the following parameters:

- .NET 5.0 (Isolated).
- Timer trigger.
- Storage Account (AzureWebJobsStorage): Storage Emulator.
- Schedule: 0 0 5 * * *

If I try to run the function (pressing F5 in the keyboard) without any changes to the code, it opens a CMD window with the colored Azure Functions logo created with characters and then the following error:

**Error: unknown argument --port**

In project properties > Debug tab > Application arguments I have `--port 7282`. I have a systray icon with this message: "Storage emulator is started".

I tried the answer of [What is the simplest way to run a timer-triggered Azure Function locally once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556621/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-run-a-timer-triggered-azure-function-locally-once) question, but I get the same error.

What do I have to do to debug the function locally? Do I need to install any specific tool?

---

If it helps, I have the following files:

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

**Function1.cs:**

```
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 5 * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
    }
}

public class MyInfo { ... }
public class MyScheduleStatus { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is port sat ?

What happens if you remove the `--port`  (can't comment due to my low rep. There for I try to give the answer)

Then try to add `RunOnStartup=true` to your Function parameter as such:

```cs
[Function("Function1")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 5 * * *") RunOnStartup=true] MyInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
    }
```

That should trigger it to run at start up for your application.

Have you looked at the [MS Learn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Edit: typo

Comment: Thank you, removing ```"commandLineArgs": "--port 7282"``` line from launchSettings.json solves the problem.

Comment: Good to hear Sometimes guides/tutorials can be more confusing that good are