# Manually trigger time based Azure Functions on dev

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My task runs once a day when deployed. For development currently I just changed the CRON to "every minute" and wait for that minute to hit in order for the function to be triggered for me to do the debugging. Is there a way such that I can leave my timer code to stay as "Every day" but still be able to kick it off manually.

In Azure I can just go to the function resource and click "Run" that will start it regardless of the timer. I am looking for something similar on my dev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest way to run a timer-triggered Azure Function locally once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556621/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-run-a-timer-triggered-azure-function-locally-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a direct solution available to manually (or even through and http request) trigger a time based Azure function.

**Possible Workaround**

Have a second http triggered function that has the same logic/code. You can use this 2nd function for testing on demand basis.

Please see the discussion in these 2 threads, it's very relevant to you -

[Any method for testing timer trigger function](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6926)

[Time triggered azure function to trigger immediately after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569926/time-triggered-azure-function-to-trigger-immediately-after-deploy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It's seems now there is a HTTP solution to execute a timer function, both [locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#non-http-triggered-functions), as well as [in the Azure cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/Azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http)

Answer (score 11):

You are probably looking for this on the Timer Trigger attribute,

```
[TimerTrigger("", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo timer
```

That should kick it off on startup.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely helpful, but what if I want to debug multiple iterations?

Answer (score 0):

As @neo99 mentioned, simple answer is it is not possible just out of the box. The reason is input parameters for ***Run*** method of Trigger function are different for different type of triggers.

For e.g. you are looking to manually trigger(HttpTrigger) a TimerTrigger

Timer Trigger:

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

Http Trigger:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, 
    TraceWriter log)
```